# How do you populate a dynamic variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic-variables

The following code gives me the error "Cannot read property PERSON1 of null". If I comment out the line where I try to assign the dynamic variable and uncomment the alert line it pops up alerts with each successive person's name.

```
    function fillInternalRepData() {

    var internalRepList = null;

    console.log("Querying Table for internal reps");
    queryTable(//..blabla..//, "false", function (callbackResp) {
        internalRepList = callbackResp;

        //            alert("TRIGGERED"); //WORKS
        //            alert(internalRepList.length); //WORKS
        angular.forEach(internalRepList, function (rep) {
            repName = rep.such;
            $scope.internalReps[repName].such = repName;
            //alert(repName); //WORKS WHEN LINE ABOVE IS COMMENTED OUT
        });


    }); //get list of internal reps
```

I simply want to create/add to the $scope.internalReps object so that I can add stuff to it like $scope.internalReps.PERSON1.Name = "Whatever"; $scope.internalReps.PERSON1.Salary = 100000;

Comment: is $scope.internalReps initialized to an object first?
Then you would also need to ensure $scope.internalReps[repName] is an object and not null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty object for the "internalReps" before your forEach loop.  It doesn't look like you've declared the object yet, so it can't dynamically add to a null object.

```
$scope.internalReps = {};
angular.forEach(internalRepList, function (rep) {
  repName = rep.such;
  $scope.internalReps[repName] = {}; 
  $scope.internalReps[repName].such = repName;
  //alert(repName);
});
```

Comment: I then get - TypeError: Cannot set property 'such' of undefined

Comment: You've got to add the property as another empty object first.


        `$scope.internalReps[repName] = {};
         $scope.internalReps[repName].such = repName;`

Comment: This works, hopefully I can pass it to $scope.internalReps when done --

Comment: var internalReps = {};

            angular.forEach(internalRepList, function (rep) {
                repName = rep.such;
                internalReps[repName] = {
                    such: ""
                };
                internalReps[repName].such = repName;

                alert(internalReps[repName].such);

            });

Answer (score 0):

```
var internalReps = {}; 
angular.forEach(internalRepList, function (rep) { 
repName = rep.such; 
internalReps[repName] = { such: "" }; 
internalReps[repName].such = repName; 
//alert(internalReps[repName].such); 
});
```

That worked. Thanks for the help!